# How to take daily snapshots of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building a sales database. One of the tables has to be a hierarchy of sales reps and their assigned territories. Ohese reps and their territories change every day, and I need to keep track of what exactly that table looks like every day. I will need to take snapshots of the table daily.

I would like to know what I have to do or how I have to store the data in the table, to be able to know exactly what the data in the table was at a certain point in time.

Is this possible?

Please keep in mind that the table will not be more than one megabyte or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using Paul Nielsen's [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/):

> AutoAudit is a SQL Server (2005, 2008) Code-Gen utility that creates
>   Audit Trail Triggers with:
>
> - Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy, and RowVersion (incrementing INT) columns to table
> - Insert event logged to Audit table
> - Updates old and new values logged to Audit table
> - Delete logs all final values to the Audit table
> - view to reconstruct deleted rows
> - UDF to reconstruct Row History
> - Schema Audit Trigger to track schema changes
> - Re-code-gens triggers when Alter Table changes the table

His original blog post: [CodeGen to Create Fixed Audit Trail Triggers](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/01/15/codegen-to-create-fixed-audit-trail-triggers.aspx)

Before you implement in production suggest you restore a backup of your database into development and work on that.

Comment: can you tell me how i would implement this for my problem?

Comment: +1 That looks pretty neat. I was going to suggest a audit trigger that would copy data into a table structure that included time/date of the copy, but this looks like it'd do the trick nicely.

Comment: @MitchWheat i dont understand how i would query to see a snapshot of a specific date since not ALL data changes

Comment: @MitchWheat i need to see the ENTIRE table in its state at a specific time

Comment: See UDF to reconstruct Row History

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry to bother you but can you please show me how i would see an entire snapshot of a table at a certain time?

Comment: also how would i modify this script to work ONLY on one table instead of all tables in the database?

Comment: @MitchWheat mate are you there

Comment: @MitchWheat trying again please help!

Comment: @MitchWheat hey mitch trying to reach you from down under

Comment: @MrMoose can you tell me please how would i recover a snapshot of the table as it was on a certain date if i have auditing on it? i cannot undersatnd how i would do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is for MS SQL.

Seeing as the table is so small, you are best of to use the Snapshot functionality provided by MS SQL.

To make a snapshot of a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE YourDB_Snapshot_DateStamp ON
( NAME = YourDB_Data, FILENAME = 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\YourDB_Snapshot_DateStamp.ss' )
AS SNAPSHOT OF YourDB;
GO
```

See this page for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx

You can make as many snapshots as you want. So my advice is to create a script or task that creates a daily snapshot and appends the date to the snapshot name. This way you will have all your snapshots visible on your server.

Important to note: Snapshots are read only.