# MERGE vs TRUNCATE and INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently upgraded to MSSQL 2008 R2 and was wondering whether or not the "new" Merge function was more efficient/faster than Truncating and Inserting for updating tables given each table has millions of rows. If anyone could provide some data of their performance, that would be great, but any explanation would be helpful!

Comment: It depends on how many rows you have to add. There probably is a threshold value where the execution time is the same for `merge` and `truncate ... insert`.

Comment: Don't forget that a `TRUNCATE` will reset your "current" identity values, whereas they will be preserved when using merge.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your point of `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` correctly. If not, then feel free to correct me.

`MERGE` is meant as a mechanism to do either an `UPDATE` to an existing row, or, in case an existing row is not found, an `INSERT`.

You suggest `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT`, which would remove the use of MERGE as everything would be an INSERT. I don't have any idea whether or not a `MERGE` in that case would be faster or not, because I never tried it, but I would assume that the part of the `MERGE` that determines whether to use an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` does impose some overhead.

Comment: I'm wondering whether or not to use MERGE instead of TRUNCATE and INSERT, not both. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Perhaps I worded myself wrongly. Like tr3, I also assumed that you are trying to copy data from one table to another. 

If this is the case, I'd stick to `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT`, because I assume the part of the `MERGE` that verifies whether or not to use an `UPDATE` adds overhead.

If you're looking for a simple way to clone a single table, you could try having a look at this SO question: 

How to take daily snapshots of a table - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813808/how-to-take-daily-snapshots-of-a-table

Answer (score 1):

I used `MERGE` because i needed to track data changes (was keeping a checksum of the rows), but since it seems that you just need that data "cloned" everytime I don't see any particular reason to use `MERGE` , after all `MERGE` does some kind of checks (there's a check on the primary keys and additional conditions are put on every `WHEN`);
by using `TRUNCATE` and then a bulk `INSERT` you shouldn't have all that conditions in play

by the way don't take this as 100% true, I don't have any performance test to bring as a proof; I suggest you to try both operations and see which one takes more time =)